# Problema ao carregar links de arquivo CSS e imagens de repositório do GitHub em projeto local - Como solucionar?

Tags: html, css, github, link

Eu criei um projeto na minha máquina local e, após finalizá-lo, fiz o upload para um repositório no GitHub. No entanto, estou enfrentando um problema com links no meu código que não estão sendo carregados corretamente no meu projeto local. Na verdade, nenhum dos links está funcionando.

Quero compartilhar o link do repositório para que vocês pudessem analisar, por gentileza.
https://github.com/mpenninck21/climafrio-solutions

Os links seriam:

1. styles.css, que está dentro da pasta "css"
2. "climafrio solutions logo.png" que está dentro da pasta "img"
3. mainbanner.jpg que está dentro da pasta "img"

Eu não sei ao certo se todos os arquivos (index.html, pasta script, pasta css, pasta img) estão dentro de uma outra pasta chamada "CLIMAFRIO-SOLUTIONS", mas acredito que talvez seja por aí o problema.

Comment: Você está usando URLs relativas à raiz do domínio (pois começam com /). Se o site estiver na raiz do domínio (por exemplo, http://localhost/index.html) deve funcionar. Ou use URLs relativas à página atual (sem a barrra no início)